# https4 apache camel gives Host name does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix, spring-dsl

i am trying to set up a https connection with apache camel in Spring DSL. following this tutorial: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html/apache_camel_component_reference/IDU-HTTP4

and also: http://camel.apache.org/http4.html

i constructed the following code:

```
<sslContextParameters id="sslContextParameters" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"> 
        <trustManagers>
            <keyStore resource="keyStore/keyStore.jks" password="changeit"/>                   
        </trustManagers>                
</sslContextParameters>
```

and my route:

```
<route id="axis_camera">
    <to uri = "https4://my_ip_adress?sslContextParametersRef=sslContextParameters"
</route>
```

and

```
<bean id="http-ssl" class="org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpComponent">
<property name="sslContextParameters" ref="sslContextParameters"/>
</bean>
```

when running this on apache servicemix i get:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name my_ip_adress does not 
match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=axis-accc8ec51452, 
O=Axis Communications AB)
```

Now i can see in the certificate that this host name is not defined in the subject. I have seen that certificates can not be edited so my question is how do i adjust this code in such a way that it reads the correct hostname?

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild guess based on available information, but give it a try.
Your certificate CN is `axis-accc8ec51452` you should be connecting to this hostname, instead of `my_ip_address`.

To map the hostname `axis-accc8ec51452` to `my_ip_address`, either update it in your DNS resolver or add it to your `hosts` file (*nix : `/etc/hosts` | Windows: `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`)

Answer (score 0):

it was quite frustrating, but with the help of @ShellDragon i searched for a bean that allows all hostnames. this bean is x509HostnameVerifier. so in my code i added this here:

```
<bean id="http-ssl" class="org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpComponent">
    <property name="sslContextParameters" ref="sslContextParameters"/>
      <property name="x509HostnameVerifier" ref = "x509HostnameVerifier"/>
    </bean>
```

and added this to my url:

```
https4://my_ip_adress?sslContextParametersRef=sslContextParameters&amp;x509HostnameVerifier=x509HostnameVerifier
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use Apache Camel you can define x509HostnameVerifier parameter in your url. Something like above:

```
<bean id="noopHostnameVerifier" class="org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier" />
```

...

```
<to uri="http: ... ?x509HostnameVerifier=#noopHostnameVerifier"/>
```